# Pointer-events: none not working on child element

Tags: css, pointer-events

I have this setup (https://jsfiddle.net/Lxcmcrx3/3/) where I want to be able to click through the labels. However setting `pointer-events: none` on the labels (.child) does not work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300" />
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Label text
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      Label text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Why is that?

It does work to move the `pointer-events: none` to the `.parent`, but that's not something I can do. Is there a way to force the pointer-events on the `.child`?

Comment: Why not attach your event to the parent container? https://jsfiddle.net/Lxcmcrx3/5/ Or does this conflict with future changes?

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Also not an option, the labels (.child) are an independent component that are added in multiple situations and as such should work/behave (click through them) regardless of situation they're used in, even independent from `.parent`.

Comment: I don't see how. You are clicking through the labels but only as far as **their parent.** Since you can't apply `pointer-events: none` to the parent I think you're at an impasse (barring javascript of course).

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm afraid you are correct. Technically it does work as designed. I'll have to find a way to put the pointer-event on the .parent to get desired result.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to click the `.parent` by going through the `.child` that doesn't register mouse clicks? You can do that by isolating the `event.target` (element that's actually clicked, i.e. `.parent`) from the `event.currentTarget` (element in which it's event listener was triggered i.e. `.container`) in the event chain.

In the demo, a button toggles the `pointer-events` property for the `.child`'s. The results should be the following:

1. If `.child` have `pointer-events: none`, then the `event.target` is `.parent`
2. If `.child` have `pointer-events: auto`, then the `event.target` is `.child`.

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/7gpsosx0/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var tgt = e.target.className;
    alert(tgt + ' is clicked.');
  }
});
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.child').toggleClass('on off');
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
}
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.child {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.on {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.on:after {
  content: 'auto';
  color: blue;
}
.off {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.off:after {
  content: 'none';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn'>
  Child PointerEvents</button>
<div class="container">
  <img class='image' src="https://unsplash.it/200/200" />
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child off">
      Label text
    </div>
    <div class="child off">
      Label text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code for testing:

> avoid events on everything : parent and children.

```css
.parent {
   pointer-events : none;
```

```js
const
  parentDIV = document.querySelector('.parent')
, childsDIV = document.querySelectorAll('.child')
  ;
parentDIV.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
  {
  console.log('>parent', target.id );
  });
childsDIV.forEach( cc =>
  {
  cc.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
    {
    console.log('>child', target.id );
    });
  });
  
btClear.onclick =_=> console.clear();
```

```css
div {
  margin     : 10px;
  padding    : 5px;
  text-align : center;
  }
.parent {
  background     : yellow;
  width          : 200px;
  pointer-events : none;  /* avoid events on everything */
  }
.child:first-of-type
  {
  background: lightgreen;
  }
.child:last-of-type
  {
  background: lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<button id="btClear">clear console</button>

<div class="parent" id="P">
  <div class="child" id="c1">
    text child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="c2">
    text child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

> avoid events only on one child, but not for his parent

```css
.child:first-of-type {
   pointer-events : none;
```

```js
const
  parentDIV = document.querySelector('.parent')
, childsDIV = document.querySelectorAll('.child')
  ;
parentDIV.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
  {
  console.log('>parent', target.id );
  });
childsDIV.forEach( cc =>
  {
  cc.addEventListener('click', ({target}) =>
    {
    console.log('>child', target.id );
    });
  });
  
btClear.onclick =_=> console.clear();
```

```css
div {
  margin     : 10px;
  padding    : 5px;
  text-align : center;
  }
.parent {
  background     : yellow;
  width          : 200px;
  }
.child:first-of-type
  {
  background     : lightgreen;
  pointer-events : none;  /* avoid events on this one only  */
  }                       /* but .parent can get any event  */
.child:last-of-type
  {
  background : lightblue;
  }
```

```html
<button id="btClear">clear console</button>

<div class="parent" id="P">
  <div class="child" id="c1">
    text child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="c2">
    text child 2
  </div>
</div>
```